# Grouped values with summed column, now i want the averages between those sums

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

If I have a group and the detail rows are summed, how could I get the average?

When rendered, my table looks like following due to the grouping

```
Column C
23
34
25
```

However, the details are actually like this

```
Column C
4
5
8
3
2
5
6
2
```

I want the averages between the grouped values as below

```
23
34
25
```

...and not the details, which would yield average values in the single digits.

Suggestions?

[edit for update]

underlying query:

```
SELECT (u.Firstname + ' ' + u.LastName) AS UserName, SUM(fa.LogCount) AS Cnt, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, 2 - DATEPART(DW, fa.LogDate),fa.LogDate),101)  AS WeekOf 
FROM dbo.ActivityLog fa
JOIN dbo.[User] u ON fa.UserKey = u.UserId
GROUP BY (u.Firstname + ' ' + u.LastName),fa.LogDate
```

So then I would get Results like this.

```
UserName      Cnt           WeekOf            
Amy Smithers      5         03/31/2014
Amy Smithers      2         03/31/2014
Amy Smithers      8                       04/07/2014
Carla Tester      3         03/31/2014
Cassandra West    13            03/31/2014
```

Now , in the report, I group on UserName and then WeekOf and im summing the Cnt column.
That combines the rows for user Amy Smithers for example and her Sum (total) would be 7 for the week of 3/31.  However, I also want the average of Cnt between the two week groups 3/31 and 4/07, not just the average over the whole period, which would be Avg(5,2,8).  Instead I want the average of (5+2, 8).  Hope this helps

[update 2]
If you read this far, this is what ended up helping me
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438(SQL.105).aspx#Aggregates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438%28SQL.105%29.aspx#Aggregates)
I just had to refer to the different groups in the correct order

Comment: Can you show the SQL you have used so far. Sounds like you are using SUM(ColC) not Avg(ColC)

Comment: Do the `sum()` query you already have in a derived table and do the `avg()` in the main query.

Comment: I found this which seems to kinda be what im struggling with  http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11579/aggregate-of-an-aggregate-function-in-ssrs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Username, AVG(CONVERT(decimal, Cnt))
from
(
  SELECT (u.Firstname + ' ' + u.LastName) AS UserName, SUM(fa.LogCount) AS Cnt, 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, 2 - DATEPART(DW, fa.LogDate),fa.LogDate),101)  AS WeekOf 
  FROM dbo.ActivityLog fa
  JOIN dbo.[User] u ON fa.UserKey = u.UserId
  GROUP BY (u.Firstname + ' ' + u.LastName),fa.LogDate
) f
group by f.Username
```

Comment: Actually, I think its turing out to be easier than I thought.  See the section on Aggregates of aggregates http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438(SQL.105).aspx#Aggregates